# Using width and transform on transition causes flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css

Check out this JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/hufibisawa/1/edit?css,js,output

Fire up Chrome:

1. Click the test button
2. Click the test2 button
3. You will see the green bar flickers. I suppose it is because a "translate3d" does not calculate its pixels the same way "width" does

When using "left" and "width" properties together it works perfectly, but it is not as performant. The reason is that translate3d triggers HW acceleration and uses sub-pixel calculations, which gives an extremely smooth animation.

Is it a bug? Is it solvable? Using Firefox this works just great! So maybe a Chrome bug?

The css

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out, width 1s ease-out;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

#test2 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s ease-out, width 1s ease-out;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

And the JS

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function () {

var el = document.querySelector('#test');
  el.style.width = '150px';
  el.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)';

  var el = document.querySelector('#test2');
  el.style.width = '150px';
  el.style.transform = 'translate3d(150px, 0px, 0)';

});

document.querySelector('#button2').addEventListener('click', function () {

var el = document.querySelector('#test');
  el.style.width = '300px';
  el.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)';

  var el = document.querySelector('#test2');
  el.style.width = '300px';
 el.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, 25px, 0)';

});
```

Comment: Even if I remove with rom transition the flicker is still there. One question what do you mean by changing "width and left is not performant" ?

Comment: Updated comment explaining that :-)

Comment: What browser are you using? As "translate3d" is using your browser engine.. And try to switch between browsers to see different behaviour.

Comment: If I use left and width it looks much smooth...but I found translate3d is performant in terms that its faster, so I guess it may not be doing calculations at that fine grain level and that may be the reason for flicker.

Comment: You know, with FireFox it works just fine. So maybe this is a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the issue by animating the green box from the right instead moving it from the left. E.G. http://jsbin.com/ximigitawe/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the example was a bit simplified. It does not necessarily render from an edge. Imagine it being three boxes where the one in the center is animated. You will get into the same issue :-/

Great suggestion though!